# CMS type access control for Trac

Tags: trac, dreamhost

I'm trying to have Public/Private appearances to a Trac Install.

I want superficial info to be public and everything 'touchy' to be hidden.

I'm not finding this kind of info easily.  Does everyone commonly publish their source code?

This is Trac 11 on Dreamhost.

Answer (score 1):

Can you elaborate on what you are asking?  What is "superficial" info and what is "touchy" info?  What exactly is the difference between a "Public" and a "Private" appearance?

Trac has a permissions system, and you can use it to give people access to various sub-components.  For example, one user might be able to access everything, while another only has read-only access to the wiki and ticket modules.  You can make things like the repository browser only available to logged-in users.  The granularity is quite coarse, unfortunately.  You can't (for example) give someone access to part of the wiki but not to another part; each component is all-or-nothing (although read and write are usually broken out separately).